# Output in an array, and then show the array value for the user

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, associative-array

My problem is that i need to store the value which appears whenever you click the 3 buttons. The code is supposed to let you have as many players as you want, and the players can "play" versus each other. And this "tool" counts whenever someone wins a round. However, i cant seem to find a way to save the output for every individual player, as it just stays the same whenever i change the player.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>title</title>
    <script>
        window.onload = oppstart;
        var spiller1poeng = 0.0;
        var spiller2poeng = 0.0;

        function oppstart() {
            var test = document.getElementById("knapp").onclick = spillere;
            var poengspiller1 = document.getElementById("spiller1vant").onclick = plusspoengsplr1;
            var dblelikt = document.getElementById("likt").onclick = beggelikt;
            var poengspiller2 = document.getElementById("spiller2vant").onclick = plusspoengplr2;
        }

        function spillere() {
            var x = document.getElementById("forstespiller").value;
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.innerHTML = x;
            document.getElementById("spiller1nedtrekk").appendChild(option);
            var z = document.getElementById("andrespiller").value;
            var option2 = document.createElement("option");
            option2.innerHTML = z;
            document.getElementById("spiller2nedtrekk").appendChild(option2);
        }

        function plusspoengsplr1() {
            var e = document.getElementById("spiller1nedtrekk");
            spiller1poeng++ + 1;
            var navnplayer1 = e.value;
            document.getElementById("spiller1antall").innerHTML = navnplayer1 + " " + "har vunnet" + " " + spiller1poeng + " " + "runder.";
        }

        function beggelikt() {
            var e = document.getElementById("spiller1nedtrekk");
            var f = document.getElementById("spiller2nedtrekk");
            var navnplayer1 = e.value;
            var navnplayer2 = f.value;
            spiller1poeng++ + 0.5;
            spiller2poeng++ + 0.5;
            document.getElementById("spiller1antall").innerHTML = navnplayer1 + " " + "har vunnet" + " " + spiller1poeng + " " + "runder.";
            document.getElementById("spiller2antall").innerHTML = navnplayer2 + " " + "har vunnet" + " " + spiller2poeng + " " + "runder.";
        }

        function plusspoengplr2() {
            var f = document.getElementById("spiller2nedtrekk");
            var navnplayer2 = f.value;
            spiller2poeng++ + 1;
            document.getElementById("spiller2antall").innerHTML = navnplayer2 + " " + "har vunnet" + " " + spiller2poeng + " " + "runder.";
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Turneringsverktøy</h1>
    <h4>Step 1. Skriv inn et navn i hver av inputboksene, du kan ha så mange du vil men "Spiller 1" vil alltid spille mot "Spiller 2"</h4>
    <h4>Step 2. Når du har skrevet inn et fint antall spillere i input-boksene (f.eks 4) velger du hvem som spiller mot hvem i nedtrekksboksene</h4>
    <h4>NB! Man kan ikke velge nye spillere etter man har begynt å telle runder vunnet, skriv ned resultatet og refresh siden om nødvendig.</h4>
    <input id="forstespiller" placeholder="Spiller 1">
    <input id="andrespiller" placeholder="Spiller 2">
    <br><br>
    <select id="spiller1nedtrekk"></select>
    <select id="spiller2nedtrekk"></select></select>
    <br><br>
    <button id="knapp">Legg til spillerene </button>
    <p></p>
    <br><br>
    <button id="spiller1vant">Spiller 1 vant</button>
    <button id="likt">Det ble likt</button>
    <button id="spiller2vant">Spiller 2 vant</button>
    <p id="spiller1antall">
        </Spiller>
    <p id="spiller2antall" </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it would be easier if your code were in English. They don't ask you to code in English ? Plus, it is an homework. You should try to do it yourself. If you are learning this then you should be able to find a solution

Comment: @Weedoze If necessary i can translate it?

Comment: You have a `</select>` tag alone + `</Spiller>` tag alone + `<p id="spiller2antall ` tag not closed

Comment: @Weedoze Thanks for telling me! Definately unintented and embarassing that i didnt notice it :,D Still doesnt help with the main problem though unfortunately.